# Is there a place I can point a domain so that it will redirect to another URL?

Tags: domain, redirect

I have two domains, and both are at different registrars, one has hosting and one doesn't. On the one that doesn't have hosting is there any place that I can point the domain so that it will redirect to my hosted domain. And I've already tried CNAME record and since my hosted domain is on a shared plan it just reaches the machines 'URL Not Available' page. Please ask questions if you need further explanations. Basically all I'm asking is if there is some sort of 'Redirect Server'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are a great many services that provide site redirection (I can't give any specific recommendations because I've never used any, but Google provideth).  You should, however, be able to get your hosting provider to add the other domain as an alias, so that the CNAME record you've already setup will work properly (and not dump to the server's "URL Not Available" page).  If they won't do that for free (it's something that takes literally 10 seconds to do and costs nothing on an ongoing basis), then I'd strongly recommend switching hosting companies.